# Is session safe enough to authenticate users?

Tags: security, session

I'm wondering if the session is safe enough to authenticate users.
Basically, when a new session is started, a server generates an unique session id.
And the id is used to differentiate different users.

However, isn't it possible for hackers to steal other's session id?
How can I prevent others from stealing my session id?
It seems to me that hackers can also guess session id by accident or brute force attack.

Could you please answer to the question so that I can understand the concept of session to be a better software developer?

Comment: Session is not used to authenticate users, it is used to ensure continuity between user action (after authentication). Are you asking about security of `Session.Id`? Is your question specific to any technology?

Comment: Hey, can you tell us what language you're talking about?

Comment: In addition to @SrikanthVenugopalan 's answer, if you're worried about Session Security you need to do some reading about session fixation and regenerate ids with each new request.

Comment: Maybe see http://security.stackexchange.com/q/24177/836

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan Thank you. You are right. Session is used to keep communicating between a server and a user. And my question is about the security of the session id. Also, it's not specific to any technologies.

Comment: @JeffFerland I'm using PHP for building a registration and a login form.

Comment: @leemo Thanks. I think that I should check session fixation and regenerating ids with each new request.

Answer (score 3):

In the wild cookies are most commonly [obtained using XSS](http://jehiah.cz/a/xss-stealing-cookies-101).  Another common method hijacking a session is sniffing the session id with a tool like [Firesheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep/).  In this case leaking the session id over HTTP would be a [violation of owasp a9 - Insufficient Transport Layer Protection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection).  If an attacker can force a victim into using a specific session id then its called [Session Fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation), and can be used to compromise an account.   [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery)  and [clickjacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) are other ways of influence a session.

I recommend reading the [Mozilla WebAppSec Secure Coding Guidelines - Session Management](https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAppSec/Secure_Coding_Guidelines#Session_Management).

Comment: Thanks. I should read many articles and take some time to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. There is a kind of attack called "session hijacking". There is also a troublesome attack that interferes in an existing session that is known as "cross-site request forgery". Various countermeasures are necessary. It's not very practical to summarize them here. But knowing the names of the attacks, you can easily go and learn about the countermeasures. For example you'll want to consult the [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) at OWASP.org.

Comment: How is CSRF an important means of Session Hijacking?

Comment: Thanks, I was not sufficiently cautious in using the lingo so I'll fix that.

Comment: @minopret Thank you. Knowing jargon is a starting point to learn something :)

Answer (score 0):

Session data is prone to attacks. [Cross-Site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) or Session riding is one method of the buzzwords that people are wary of.

Several articles on CSRF already mentioned here.

But in general hijacking session is a security aspect of any (session-aware) web application. Man-in-the-middle (MITM) attack is something that would expose sensitive data to unauthorized user. A good write-up on MITM is [here on OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack). A few examples of MITM on this [blog](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2013/01/man-in-the-midd_6.html).

While most articles provide a background on a few vulnerabilities that could arise by not implementing measures against session hijacking, the good news is that there are tools that allow us to test the application for these vulnerabilities. Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP) has already been mentioned. OWASP provides [guide for building secure websites](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Guide_Project)(quite general themes),  [checklist for Session Management testing](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Session_Management) and also some [resources/tools and examples](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Session_Management) to check specific aspect of session.

These articles mentioned give ways to test for such vulnerabilities. Like you've already mentioned, a bit of reading would help you.